# Mongo adding an object to original object

Tags: mongodb-query

I am not sure if I am asking the correct question but I assume this is just a basic `mongodb` question.

I currently have this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"),
"fullname" : "test",
"username" : "test",
"email" : "test@gmail.com",
"password" : "$2a$10$Wl29i6FemBrnOKq/ZErSguxlfvqoayZQkaEDirkmDl5O3GDEQjOV2"
}
```

and I would like to add an exercise object like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"),
"fullname" : "test",
"username" : "test",
"email" : "test@gmail.com",
"password" : "$2a$10$Wl29i6FemBrnOKq/ZErSguxlfvqoayZQkaEDirkmDl5O3GDEQjOV2",
"exercises": {
            "benchpress",
            "rows",
            "curls",
}
```

I am just unsure how to create exercises with the object without using `$push` which just opens up an array. I don't want an array, I want an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

An `object` is a key-value pair. In your representation of the second document, you have a nested document `exercises` as a key and its value as an object containing only strings. Don't you see something strange there? An object without keys?

It should probably be an `array` of strings. Note that an `array` is indeed an `object` where the key is the numeric index starting from 0 and the value is the `string` in that position.

(You have an additional comma and a missing `curly-brace`. Lets fix that.)
This is the document we wish to see after updating the document.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"),
  "fullname" : "test",
  "username" : "test",
  "email" : "test@gmail.com",
  "password" : "$2a$10$Wl29i6FemBrnOKq/ZErSguxlfvqoayZQkaEDirkmDl5O3GDEQjOV2",
  "exercises": [
        "benchpress",
        "rows",
        "curls"
  ]
}
```

Now, back to your question. How can we update the existing document with the exercises document? Its pretty simple. Mongodb has a 'update' method which exactly does that. Since we don't want to replace the entire document and just add additional fields, we should use `$set` to update specific fields. Fire up the mongo shell and switch to your database using `use db-name`. Then execute the following command. I assume you have an existing document with `id` ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"). Note that ObjectId is a `BSON` datatype.

```
 db.scratch.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335") }, { $set: {"exercises": ["benchpress", "rows", "curls"] } })
```

This will update the document as

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"),
  "fullname" : "test",
  "username" : "test",
  "email" : "test@gmail.com",
  "password" : "$2a$10$Wl29i6FemBrnOKq/ZErSguxlfvqoayZQkaEDirkmDl5O3GDEQjOV2",
  "exercises" : [
    "benchpress",
    "rows",
    "curls"
  ]
}
```

Here scratch refers to the collection name. The `update` method takes 3 parameters.

1. Query to find the document to update
2. The Update parameter(document to update). You can either replace the whole document or just specific parts of the document(using $set).
3. An optional object which can tell Mongodb to insert the record if the document doesn't exist(`upsert`) or update multiple documents that match the criteria(`multiple`).

**EXTRA**

Warning: If you execute the following in the mongo shell,

```
db.scratch.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335") },  {"exercises": ["benchpress", "rows", "curls"] })
```

the entire document would be replaced except the `_id` field. So, the record would be something like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57af98d4d71c4efff5304335"),
  "exercises" : [
    "benchpress",
    "rows",
    "curls"
  ]
}
```

You should only do this when you are aware of the consequence.

Hope this helps.

For more, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/